# FBlogin dialog box orientation

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm facing a very silly problem and its really hard to resolve for me.

The `fblogindialog` box that I'm using in my application, appearing in portrait mode always.. But my whole application is in landscape mode.. the main thing is that the keyboard appears landscape and the web view in which the login appears has the orientation which just suits the landscape mode (means the username and password text boxes are that much wide so that if we rotate the device it would just fit into the landscape mode).

I tried every thing I looked for the status bar orientation as well. its really frustrating. I'm using a button named post and on the click of this button I wrote the following code:

```
AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate =(AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication  sharedApplication]delegate];
    if (appDelegate._session == nil)
    {
        appDelegate._session = [FBSession sessionForApplication:_APP_KEY secret:_SECRET_KEY delegate:self];
    }

    if(self.loginDialog == NULL || ![appDelegate._session resume])
    {
        self.loginDialog  = [[[FBLoginDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    
        loginDialog.delegate = self;    
        [self.loginDialog show];
        //self.loginDialog.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
        [self.view addSubview:loginDialog];
    }
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but have you tried using ShareKit? http://www.getsharekit.com/

Comment: no i havent tried for share kit... i  just used Facebook Connect for iPhone SDK  and got the code from http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/.. working all fine just 2 issues .. one is login box nd other how wil i share some text from my own app written in a textfield..

Comment: hey noam share kit doesnt have show how to share the text on user's wall... it just logs user in and then shows the facebook jst as we c it in browser... i just want to disply a msg to the user that ur new status was posted ... thts it .. and i used fbconnect for it and working fine.. but cant find out orientation issue

Comment: You said "share kit doesnt have show how to share the text on user's wall", although I do think it does (unless I didn't understand what you mean correctly)

Comment: I'm not sure how share kit work actually .Can u just gimme a sample of how to post a line of text on a perticular user's wall ? and what delegate methods are there so that user can be informed that his text has been posted on user's wall. m really sorry for my less understanding of the new frameworks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i used new facebook sdk to solve this problem. and used the graph apis . A sample which explain all of this is --

https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

and very helpful indeed.

Thanks